# Precocious Apprentice + 14+ Ability Score

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spell-slots

Does the 2nd Lvl slot given by Precocious Apprentice qualify the character for bonus spells of second level with a ability score of 14 or higher in the corresponding ability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 2nd-level bonus spells aren't gained *solely* from having a high ability score and taking Precocious Apprentice

[Abilities and Spellcasters](http://dndsrd.net/basics.html#abilities-and-spellcasters), in part, says

> The ability that governs bonus spells depends on what type of spellcaster your character is: Intelligence for wizards; Wisdom for clerics, druids, paladins, and rangers; or Charisma for sorcerers and bards. **In addition to having a high ability score, a spellcaster must be of high enough class level to be able to cast spells of a given spell level.**… For instance, the wizard Mialee has an Intelligence score of 15, so she’s smart enough to get one bonus 1st-level spell and one bonus 2nd-level spell. (**She will not actually get the 2nd-level spell until she is 3rd level wizard, since that’s the minimum level a wizard must be to cast 2nd-level spells.**) (*Player's Handbook* 7—8 and emphasis mine)

Despite the feat **Precocious Apprentice** granting the creature "an extra 2nd-level spell slot that must be used initially to cast only the chosen spell" (*Complete Arcane* 181), as illustrated above until the creature's class levels in its arcane casting classes allow it to cast 2nd-level spells, the creature just doesn't get 2nd-level bonus spells due to a high ability score.

Answer (score 0):

No: their 2nd level "spells per day" column still has a value of "-", so they wouldn't qualify for bonus spells of that level.

Comment: This is correct, but without backing up the fact that the dash means what you claim, the answer seems incomplete.